# Fixed VS Flexible roles in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I was reading an article at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/561797/Top-20-exciting-features-of-SQL-Server-2012-Part-2#Featurenumber9(Revolution):-Powerview

There I read

`Let’s say you have two sets of database user one programmers and the other DBA’s. The programmers should be able to fire insert, update and delete queries while DBA’s should be able to create database, backup and do maintenance related activities. But DBA’s should not be able to fire insert, update and delete queries.` **But now because you have fixed roles the DBA’s get more access so they can even fire insert, update and delete queries**.
`In simple words we need flexible roles.`

Now I want to clarify what does he meant by lines which I made bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexible role meanse user defined roles.
If a user is member of a fixed role so it might have resource access more than it permissed.
So user defined roles (flexible roles) are come in help to limit access as we need.
For example a user should just have insert permission on an special table and not more. We can not reach it with fixed database role so we should create user defined roles .

Comment: That means fixed roles are of no use?

Comment: No that is not what im saying. Read carefully.